# SAS Drop Condition Output - Not enough variables observed in Output

Tags: sas, sampling, waterfall

I am learning drop_conditions in SAS. I am requesting a sample on three variables, however only two observations are retrieved. Please advise! Thank you!

```
data temp;
set mydata.ames_housing_data;
format drop condition $30.;
if (LotArea in (7000:9000)) then drop_condition = '01: Between 7000-9000 sqft';
else if (LotShape EQ 'IR3') then drop_condition = '02: Irregular Shape of Property';
else if (condition1 in 'Artery' OR 'Feedr') then drop_condition = '03: Proximity to arterial/feeder ST';

run;

proc freq data=temp;
tables drop_condition;
title 'Sample Waterfall';
run; quit;
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions/comparisons aren't specified correctly, I think you're looking for the `IN` operator to do multiple comparisons in a single line. I'm surprised there aren't errors in your log.

Rather than the following:

```
if (LotArea = 7000:9000)
```

Try:

```
if (lotArea in (7000:9000))
```

and

```
if (condition1 EQ 'Atrery' OR 'Feedr')
```

should be

```
if (condition1 in ('Atrery', 'Feedr'))
```

EDIT:
You also need to specify a length for the drop_condition variable, instead of a format to ensure the variable is long enough to hold the text specified. It's also useful to verify your answer afterwards with a proc freq against the specified conditions, for example:

```
proc freq data=temp;
where drop_condition=:'01';
tables drop_condition*lot_area;
run;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response! I changed the first argument, but still receive [Expecting an relational or arithmetic operator] after changing the second.

Comment: I edited the main post with your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a log or the second suggestion. Try the proc freq check I suggested as well.

Comment: I replaced the original code with the two suggestions. I'll try using the proc freq argument. Thanks.

Comment: Double check the second one. In needs the values listed between brackets, not OR.